# Importing dates from excel to plot as samples over time

Tags: r, date, plot

I am importing a list of samples (with dates taken) and would like to plot them as sampling frequency over time

Imported data (event date = d/m/Y) from .csv as "col_character()"

I'm a complete novice - where do I start?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! The question is quiet unclear. Please try to explain that others can understand it well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example data to transform character class date into plottable format.

```
set.seed(4) # to ensure replicability
dat <- data.frame(date=sprintf("%02d/01/2019", 1:31), value = sample(1:10, 31, replace=TRUE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

str(dat)
# 'data.frame': 31 obs. of  2 variables:
#   $ date : chr  "01/01/2019" "02/01/2019" "03/01/2019" "04/01/2019" ...
# $ value: int  1 6 2 4 7 8 6 3 1 1 ...

dat$date <- as.Date(dat$date, format="%d/%m/%Y") #transfor the character format into date format

str(dat)
# 'data.frame': 31 obs. of  2 variables:
#   $ date : Date, format: "2019-01-01" "2019-01-02" "2019-01-03" "2019-01-04" ...
# $ value: int  1 6 2 4 7 8 6 3 1 1 ...

with(dat, plot(date, value, type="l")) #simple line plot
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Adam, I'll give it a try - this looks like exactly what I was trying to achieve!